Why is the stab trim set to 4 units nose up during taxi in the Boeing 737, instead of using 5 units universally?

In our airline's SOPs and presumably other airlines too, according to the FCOM, the stabiliser trim is set to 4 units nose up during the taxi-in phase. However, in winter operations, this changes to 5 units to prevent water from snow and ice from running into the tailcone, where it could freeze and affect control surfaces.
I understand the reason for using 5 units in winter, but I'm curious as to why we can't just use 5 units all the time. I haven't been able to find any specific reference to the advantage of using 4 units in the FCOM, FCTM, or AFM.

Is there an engineering or operational reason behind preferring 4 units for normal conditions?
Could it have to do with wind conditions or some other factor during parking?
Is there any known evidence or safety data suggesting that 4 units is better than 5 in non-winter conditions?

It seems like using a single setting year-round would simplify operations, so I'm wondering what makes 4 units preferable in most cases.

Don't know for certain, but a guess is that the stab setting is that which provides a trim speed in the ballpark of the single engine safety speed after rotation, V2+x, and in winter temperatures the performance improvement of the low temp makes that setting tolerable control wise whereas it is not when warm.

That's interesting, I've never heard of guidance to do either of those things.  Running the trim back into the green band, typically around 5-7 units, is quite common, after landing mainly because that's about where it'll need to be for the next takeoff, and if the next crew overlooks enough steps in the checklists to not set the trim to the specific value from the takeoff data, well, at least it's not going to be wildly off when they go to rotate. Our cold weather procedures (which have changed over time) simply require it to be in the green band, not "4.0" or "5.0" or any specific value.

I have found a reference in our OMB that setting stab trim to 4 is a precaution to minimize aft centre of gravity movement (a tipping precaution). Surely it can't have that much impact?
